# Water heater requiring 30A breaker running on 20A

Tags: circuit-breaker, water-heater

I called a plumber to upgrade my water heater. The current breaker is a 20A. The new water heater requires a 30A.
But my wiring is #12.

The plumber said, without much conviction, that it's fine for now, and installed the new water heater.

My current setup is:

```
20A breaker 240V, #12 wire, new water heater.
```

As soon as possible, I'll upgrade to:

```
30A breaker 240V, #10 wire.
```

What's the worst that can happen in the mean time ?

Comment: If everything is installed correctly (except not upsized), you should get nuisance trips when the heater draws more than 20A. What is the model # of the heater?

Comment: Is this a one pole breaker (120V circuit) or a two pole breaker (240V circuit)?

Comment: Look into ThreePhaseEel's question.  I edited my answer to cover it.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It's a two pole breaker (240V circuit)

Comment: @manassehkatz Sorry I forgot to check, I'll look it up this evening. What do you mean by "not upsized" ?

Comment: "not upsized" refers to the 20A breaker not being replaced with a 30A breaker. So the question is: Is the voltage correct (i.e., correctly installed on 240V circuit) and everything else "just right" except that the breaker (and likely the wire) are 20A instead of 30A? As others have noted, there are big differences depending on whether this is a 30A 240V water heater running on a 20A 240V circuit (i.e., just undersized) vs. running on a 20A 120V circuit (wrong type of circuit).

Comment: Edited my description for clarification,

Comment: *What's the worst that can happen in the mean time ?* **Overheated wire causing a fire** My advice is to get this fixed ASAP since if the breaker isn't tripping you are not protected. If you can't get it fixed really soon, turn the water heater to the **lowest** setting - that way it will not have to run for quite as long.

Comment: Model: Giant 172STE-3S8M-E8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard 240V water heater only has one speed (choice of amp draw): 23A.  That is how all such hot water heaters are sized.  The reason is they want it as fast as possible while falling within a statutory 24A limit.

> Edit: ThreePhaseEel brings up an interesting point.  A 30A hot water heater *implies* that it is 240V, because it's cheaper to bump volts to 240 before amps to 30. However, you didn't *tell us* the old service was 240V (meaning a 2-pole "double" breaker in the panel).  *If this is in fact a 120V heater, that changes things.*  I'll describe this difference inside this box.
>
> First, make sure this is a "plain old resistive heater" and **not** a hybrid or heat-pump heater. The trick I'm about to describe won't work with a hybrid.
>
> Now I said "resistive" - the heating element is a **resistor**, which is the simplest electronic device on earth, and it follows simple rules, starting with Ohm's Law: **Voltage = Current x Resistance**.  Resistance is defined by how the heater is built.   So what happens if we run it on 120V?
>
> Well, since Resistance is fixed -- if Voltage drops by 50%, so must Current.  That means on 120V, this same water heater will draw 11.5 amps, and will be within safety limits of a 15A/120V circuit, and will not trip breakers.  However since **useful power = voltage x current**, and both those are halved, useful power is 1/4.
>
> What does that mean for heater *performance*?  Assuming it's Energy Star, the insulation is tip top.  It **will** reach target temperature ........... eventually. And it will take 4 times longer to get there.   You'll want to follow the conservation tips in my last paragraph.
>
> This use on 120V is safe, and it's safe indefinitely.

Now back to the 240V scenario.

*All of the advice to follow violates Code. The **only** Code-correct solution is correct cable and breaker, but you knew that.*

So expect a lot of breaker trips.

Wait 1 hour before resetting it.  That is because of this particular situation - we know exactly why it is tripping, so the consequences of resetting it too soon are also known.

If you upgrade the cable to #10 copper (10/2 will suffice), then you can reset it as often as you please.  I am assuming perhaps it is hard to obtain the right breaker due to obsolescence (PushMatic) or complexity (quadplex).

If you have a Federal Pacific, Zinsco or Challenger panel, those panels are dangerous and you are already playing with fire, so *don't push your luck with those panels*.

You will have fewer trips if you take great pains to use hot water VERY sparingly - follow California drought or boondocking-in-RV rules. Get wet, shut the water off, lather up, then do a quick rinse... Select cold water in dishwasher and washing machine... Let the soap do the cleaning not the heat... Etc.

Comment: If his HWH was hooked up to a 120V circuit, then his breaker won't trip -- he'll just get a rather lukewarm performance from his HWH.

Comment: Thank for your explanations. It's a two pole breaker (240V circuit). I already found the perfect 30A breaker. The main issue is rewiring (through walls) from #12 to #10 which I'll leave to a professional in the next few weeks. The part that surprises me is that I thought the breaker would trip when the heater drew massive amount of electrity and I assumed that would happen when first plugging it in, since the water is completely cold... and it didn't trip yet, surpringsly.

Comment: @PhilippeCarriere Glad it's working, but don't install the 30A breaker! **Breakers protect wires**.

Comment: @PhilippeCarriere Breakers are typically (but not always) designed to not trip on a small overcurrent immediately. That allows, for example, for an air conditioner compressor or other motor with large startup current to work despite needing, for a short time, more current than the circuit is rated for. If the water heater is drawing 24A (should not pulling more than that as others have noted), then it should not trip immediately, but should after some moderate amount of time (a few minutes perhaps). So if it has been running, heating coil on, for long periods of time then that is NOT good.

Comment: @PhilippeCarriere as it would imply the breaker is not tripping when it should, and therefore not protecting the #12 wire that will overheat with 24A running continuously for an extended time. Breakers - like any other electronics - are not perfect and may be a little off spec. But if is in a mode where it will trip at 25A and not at 24A **and** you are running a continuous 24A load (which you probably are) then that is not providing the necessary protection.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the warnings and concerns :) The 30A breaker is sitting on a shelf. I will install it only after I have #10 wires in the walls.

Comment: I'll lower the temperature as a precaution and hurry to fix the problem.

Comment: I would just move the white wire off the breaker and onto the neutral bar, making it the 120V scenario described in the  yellow box.  You can run that way forever without worry.